# Can bright light sources like LED flashlights damage the photodiodes of optical heart rate sensors used in smartwatches?

Tags: photodiode

Suppose a 3 - 3.3 V white (or any colour) LED with 800 Lm (theoretical max 1800 Lm), 5592 Cd or more is shone into the optical heart rate sensor on the back of a smartwatch at close range (< 10 cm) for a short period of time (few minutes). Will the photodiodes be damaged by this light or will it negatively impact readings accuracy? Does it matter if the watch is turned on and the sensor actively measuring?

Comment: You probably could not put enough light to do damage with just an LED.

Comment: It's impossible to give an absolute answer. There *may* be some very sensitive photo diodes that *could* be damaged by a very bright light source (laser?) but, like the comment above, I doubt that the vast majority would be. After all, if there is no warning not to expose it to direct sunlight, which is much brighter than a torch, you will be OK.

Comment: @conste Did you notice such damage or is this hypothetical?

Comment: @datenheim Just hypothetically. Was wondering how sensitive those photodiodes are but the comparison with sunlight gives perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Theoreticalky it may degrade the photodiode, but if that change is detectable, or if it degrades at all in 10 minutes can't be told per se.

It depends on too many unspecified parameters like emission spectra of the LED, window and filter on the photodiode, photodiode material and type and quality, if a temperature increase is happening and so on.

For instance should the LED emit some residual UV light (halogen lamps do that, sunlight as well has notable UV energy) that may degrade a plastic window or even the photodiode die. But I doubt that 10 minutes are enough time. If the sensor get's heated up considerably the supports the degradation.

It seems unlikely that the photocurrent generated could do any harm to the photodiode or other circuits, even if the sensor is unpowered.